# ¿Cómo eliminar coincidencias en un vector?

Tags: php

Tengo un vector en PHP que contiene verduras en las posiciones impares y sus pesos en pares. En el vector se repiten las verduras y me gustaría saber cómo podría conseguir el total de pesos sin repetir las verduras.

Origen:

```
$verduras = array("tomate",15,"patata",10,"tomate",5,"patata",1,"boniato",5,"boniato",10,"ajo",20,"tomate",2);
```

Deseado:

```
$verduras = array("tomate",22,"patata",11,"boniato",15,"ajo",5);
```

He pensado que se puede utilizar la función array_keys() pero NO tengo claro si es la manera óptima o existe algún planteamiento mejor.

Con el uso de array_keys() lo puedo aplicar para las verduras que devuelvan un valor superior a 1, pero no sé cómo descartar si esa verdura ya ha sido tratada previamente.

En realidad quiero hacer algo similar a distinct de SQL en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre recorrer el array con un `for` de 2 en 2 y luego inicialmente crear un *array asociativo* donde cada coincidencia del item `$i`, se le va sumando la cantidad encontrada en `$i+1`;

```
<?php
$verduras = array("tomate",15,"patata",10,"tomate",5,"patata",1,"boniato",5,"boniato",10,"ajo",20,"tomate",2);
$cantidad = count($verduras);
$totales = array();
for($i=0; $i<$cantidad-1; $i+=2) {
    $key = $verduras[$i];
    if(array_key_exists($key, $totales)) {
        // Si la verdura ya existe en el array asociativo, entonces sumar el valor
        $totales[$key] += $verduras[$i+1];
    } else {
        // Si la verdura NO existe, entonces crearla con el valor respectivo
        $totales[$key] = $verduras[$i+1];
    }
}
```

La salida de este script es, obviamente, un array asociativo:

```
print_r($totales);
// array('tomate'=>22, 'patata'=>11, 'boniato'=>15, 'ajo'=>20);
```

Si deseas revertirlo a array indexado numéricamente

```
$verduras = array(); // Sobreescribe la variable $verduras original
foreach($totales as $key=>$value) {
    $verduras[] = $key;
    $verduras[] = $value;
}
print_r($verduras);
// array(tomate, 22, patata, 11, boniato, 15, ajo, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir elementos únicos en un array PHP se usa la función [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php), si bien **NO puedes usarla** directamente **porque tu array de datos no tiene una estructura que se preste**. *Personalmente, creo que hay estructuras más coherentes para almacenar los datos.*

En respuesta a tu pregunta

> vector en PHP que contiene verduras en las posiciones impares y sus pesos en pares

y buscas

> conseguir el total de pesos sin repetir las verduras.

partiendo del siguiente array:

```
$verduras = [
    "tomate", 15,
    "patata", 10,
    "tomate", 5,
    "patata", 1,
    "boniato", 5,
    "boniato", 10,
    "ajo", 20,
    "tomate", 2
];
```

**hay que usar un *script* a medida**, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    $vegetables_and_weights = [
        "tomate", 15,
        "patata", 10,
        "tomate", 5,
        "patata", 1,
        "boniato", 5,
        "boniato", 10,
        "ajo", 20,
        "tomate", 2
    ];

$temp = [];
$unique_values = array_unique($vegetables_and_weights);

foreach ($unique_values as $value){
    if (is_string($value)) {
        $temp[] = $value;
    }
}

// En este punto $temp guarda sólo nombres de verduras, sin repeticiones.
// Voy a ordenar los nombres, puedes omitir este paso:
sort($temp);

// $temp guarda: ['ajo', 'boniato', 'patata', 'tomate']
// Ahora, voy a usar una nueva estructura: un array asociativo, 
// donde las claves sean los nombres de las verduras y los valores
// sus pesos
$result = [];

// Obtengo con una función los pesos para cada vegetal del array de partida:
function getVegetableWeight($vegetables_and_weights, $vegetable)
{
    $weight = 0;
    foreach ($vegetables_and_weights as $key => $value){
        if ($value === $vegetable) {
            $weight_position = $key + 1;
            $vegetable_weight = $vegetables_and_weights[$weight_position];

            $weight += $vegetable_weight;
        }
    }

    return $weight;
}

foreach ($temp as $vegetable){
    $result[$vegetable] = getVegetableWeight($vegetables_and_weights, $vegetable);
}


// Resultado final:
print_r($result); 
/*
Array
(
    [ajo] => 20
    [boniato] => 15
    [patata] => 11
    [tomate] => 22
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que se me ocurrió fue crear un arreglo asociativo para ir sumando las cantidades en un ciclo y después recorrerlo para generar nuevamente el arreglo con el formato original `[nombre, cantidad, ... , 'nombre, cantidad]`

```
$verduras = array("tomate",15,"patata",10,"tomate",5,"patata",1,"boniato",5,"boniato",10,"ajo",20,"tomate",2);
// Crear un arreglo para agregar los elementos
$filtro = [];
// Sumar 2 en cada iteración para obtener:
// nombre: $verduras[$i]
// cantidad: $verduras[$i + 1]
for($i = 0; $i < count($verduras); $i += 2) {
    // Verificar si nombre no existe en filtro
    if(!isset($filtro[$verduras[$i]])) {
        // No existe, hay que agregarlo e inicializar en cero
        $filtro[$verduras[$i]] = 0;
    }
    // Sumar la cantidad
    $filtro[$verduras[$i]] += $verduras[$i + 1];
}
// Inicializar $verduras como arreglo vacío
$verduras = [];
// Agregar nombre, cantidad
foreach($filtro as $nombre => $cantidad) {
    $verduras[] = $nombre;
    $verduras[] = $cantidad;
}
```

> Resultado: `["tomate", 22, "patata", 11, "boniato", 15, "ajo", 20]`

Answer (score -1):

Directamente puedes usar la funcion array_unique() que te saco solo os elementos unicos en el arreglo, algo asi:

```
$verduras = array("tomate",15,"patata",10,"tomate",5,"patata",1,"boniato",5,"boniato",10,"ajo",20,"tomate",2);
$result = array_unique($verduras);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: En tu código el resultado sería:

Comment: Tu código NO funciona, va a eliminar los nombres de verduras y pesos repetidos. El array resultante no resuelve el problema ni va a servir para nada. Resultado: `['tomate', 15, 'patata', 10, 5, 1, 'boniato', 'ajo', 20, 2]`